# Lodash debounce only delays for first call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash, debouncing

I have an input box where the user can manually enter the quantity and also plus(+) minus(-) signs so that they can add/remove by clicking on the plus or minus signs.

What I am trying to achieve is that when the user clicks, let's say plus multiple times, instead of sending that post request multiple times after 500 ms send the request when the user stops clicking for 500 ms.

debounce function comes from lodash

Here is my code;

```
  const debouncedUpdateItemQuantity = debounce((id, qty) => {
     updateItemQuantity(id, qty);
  }, 500);


  const updateItemQuantity =  (id, qty) => {
   dispatch(
     updateQuantity(
       id,
       qty,
       () => {
         dispatch(getBasket());
       }
     )
   );
```

};

and my html

```
 <div>
   <span
     onClick={() => debouncedUpdateItemQuantity(id,itemQty)}
   > 
     - 
   </span>
   <input
     type="text"
     value={itemQty}
   />

   <span
     onClick={() => debouncedUpdateItemQuantity(id,itemQty)}
   > 
     + 
   </span>
 </div>
```

This code delays the first call but if the user clicks 10 times it is making a request for all other clicks after 500 ms. How can I prevent this and how can make it so that only the last click is fetched after the user waits 500 ms. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `debounce` inside of a react component's render function (the function itself for function components). Ever time react rerenders this component, `debounce` is getting called again. You will need to [useCallback](https://react.dev/reference/react/useCallback) to get this to work properly. Something like this:

```js
import {useCallback} from "react"

const debouncedUpdateItemQuantity = useCallback(debounce((id, qty) => {
    updateItemQuantity(id, qty);
}, 500), [updateItemQuantity])


const updateItemQuantity = useCallback((id, qty) => {
  dispatch(
    updateQuantity(
      id,
      qty,
      () => {
        dispatch(getBasket());
      }
    )
  );
}, [])
```

### Note

I should mention that you will probably need to update the dep arrays to fit your specific use case. You should almost certainly put `getBasket`, `dispatch`, and `updateQuantity` into the dep array for the `updateItemQuantity` `useCallback`. I don't know how your code is structured, though and most likely if you add these without restructuring your other code, it will break, and I wanted you to be able to test it right away. You should wrap all of those other functions in `useCallback` with the appropriate dep arrays for each and then add them to the dep array of `updateItemQuantity` as well

Comment: `useCallback` takes two arguments. The second one is the dependency array. You should specify all dependencies

Comment: @Konrad Thanks! Haven't used react in a while but am very familiar with it's execution model. I thought it inferred empty dep arrays, but it doesn't. Will add them

Comment: @Konrad I added a note about the dep arrays as well. I had that in my head but forgot to actually write it out initially